# SQL - Find cycle and duration

Tags: sql, postgresql

I search a solution for my problem in SQL (postgresql).

I have a logs table with the following columns:

| deviceId | id | code | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| device1 | 1 | 12 | 1672597471000 |
| device1 | 2 | 11 | 1672597471001 |
| device1 | 3 | 8 | 1672597471002 |
| device1 | 4 | 2 | 1672597471003 |
| device1 | 5 | 9 | 1672597471004 |
| device1 | 6 | 9 | 1672597471005 |
| device1 | 7 | 4 | 1672597471006 |
| device1 | 8 | 8 | 1672597471007 |
| device1 | 9 | 9 | 1672597471008 |
| device2 | 1 | 8 | 1672597471000 |
| device2 | 2 | 9 | 1672597471010 |
| device2 | 3 | 12 | 1672597471050 |
| device2 | 4 | 8 | 1672597471100 |
| device2 | 5 | 9 | 1672597471130 |

I search one query (or more) to find the time elapsed between  two codes (8 and 9 for example).
The output of SQL query will be:

| deviceId | elapsed time |
| --- | --- |
| device1 | 2 |
| device1 | 1 |
| device2 | 10 |
| device2 | 30 |

I would really appreciate if anyone can suggest some ideas how to solve this problem.

I tried with lead function but i can't reset time between each sequence (8 and 9) and ignore unique 8 or 9. In short, i'm stuck and I don't know if it's possible in SQL.

Comment: something like this `select deviceid, (Max(timestamp)-min(timestamp)) as elapsed group by deviceid, id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using the window function `lag()` to obtain the previous row of the current row, followed by subtraction to obtain the elapsed time between 8 and 9 using the condition `where code = 9 and lag_code = 8`:

```
 with cte as (
  select *, 
            lag(timestamp) over (partition by deviceid order by timestamp) as lag_timestamp,
            lag(code) over (partition by deviceid order by timestamp) as lag_code
  from mytable
  where code between 8 and 9
)
select deviceId, timestamp - lag_timestamp as elapsed_time
from cte
where code = 9 and lag_code = 8
```

Result :

| deviceid | elapsed_time |
| --- | --- |
| device1 | 2 |
| device1 | 1 |
| device2 | 10 |
| device2 | 30 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/sVIZHVw1)

Comment: Awesome, it seems to work with the various tests I do. Thank you for your time. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple query to produce the result you need (and [test it on fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oiopXrKe)) :

```
select a.deviceId, (b.timestamp - a.timestamp) as elapsed_time
from logs a join logs b
on b.deviceid = a.deviceid
and b.id = (select min(id)
            from logs b
            where b.deviceid = a.deviceid
            and b.id > a.id
            and code = 9)
where a.code = 8;
```

and it gives:

```
 deviceid | elapsed_time 
----------+--------------
 device1  |            2
 device1  |            1
 device2  |           10
 device2  |           30
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. It works also expect if there is a code 8 without code 9. 
The query of @SelVazi works in any situation. Thanks to you two.